# import excel data into ms access using python

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

i am trying to import a excel data in to ms access file using python.

below my code;

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.parse
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import os

os.getcwd()
Chd= os.chdir('D:/NX_BACKWORK/Feeder Setup_PROCESS')
Chd = os.getcwd()

#xls = pd.ExcelFile('Upload-Data.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')
df1 = pd.read_excel('123.xlsx', sheet_name='T_PBAR')

print(df1.head(10))
print('open mdb')

cnnstr = (
    r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
    r"DBQ=D:\NX_BACKWORK\Feeder Setup_PROCESS\MODEL.mdb"
)

cnnurl = f"access+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={urllib.parse.quote_plus(cnnstr)}"
acc_engine = create_engine(cnnurl)
print('writing to access')
df1.to_sql("T_PBAR",acc_engine, if_exists='append')

print('write complete')
```

this is error i am facing in below line

```
df1.to_sql("T_PBAR",acc_engine, if_exists='append')
```

Exception has occurred: InterfaceError
(pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/rvf5)
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Users\zen\OneDrive\Documents\Python\PandasAPP\TESTNGpy.py", line 67, in 
df1.to_sql("T_PBAR",acc_engine, if_exists='append')
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/rvf5)

need a support

Answer (score 0):

i used to check the below cmd.

```
print(pyodbc.drivers())
```

in console output: ['SQL Server']

go to control panel system security > Administrative Tools> ODBC datasource (32/64 bit) > Driver > check what is installed in it if its not install the Microsoft Access Database Engine.